# Как заменить в ajax form в modx, jgrowl - своим элементом?

Tags: ajax, modx

Как заменить в ajax form в modx, jgrowl - своим элементом ?

```
[[!AjaxForm? &snippet=FormIt &form=tpl.AjaxForm.example &hooks=email &emailSubject=Тестовое сообщение &emailTo=info@domain.com &validate=name:required,email:required,message:required &validationErrorMessage=В форме содержатся ошибки! &successMessage=Сообщение успешно отправлено ]]
```

Вот вызов ajax, при успешной отправке выводится `&successMessage` (Сообщение успешно отправлено).

Нужно изменить модальное окно (сообщение успешно отправлено).

jgrow - не хочется переписывать css, легче создать своё модальное окно со своим текстом и задать нужные стили.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: [[!AjaxForm?
    &snippet=`FormIt`
    &form=`tpl.AjaxForm.example`
    &hooks=`email`
    &emailSubject=`Тестовое сообщение`
    &emailTo=`info@domain.com`
    &validate=`name:required,email:required,message:required`
    &validationErrorMessage=`В форме содержатся ошибки!`
    &successMessage=`Сообщение успешно отправлено`
]]
Вот вызов ajax, при успешной отправке выводится &successMessage=`Сообщение успешно отправлено`. 
Нужно изменить !!!модальное окно (сообщение отправлено). jgrow - не хочется переписывать css, легче создать своё модальное окно и его выводить. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Отключите jgrowl, переопределите своей логикой. Вот два полезных материала, как это можно сделать:
[Сообщение об успешной отправке AjaxForm в модалке](https://ilyaut.ru/cheats/message-about-successful-sending-ajaxform-in-module/)

[Ajax форма обратной связи для MODX](https://modzone.ru/blog/2015/12/23/ajax-feedback-form/)